# SAPUI5: Get event when form has been fully rendered

Tags: javascript, events, sapui5

I am creating a SAPUI5 VBox with forms and form containers being able to print the data. As the binding and the creation of the forms happen asynchronously, I am not able to capture the event when the forms have been rendered completely.

I tried onAfterRendering of the VBox but this was triggered too early. So I made an ugly hack and attached an onAfterRendering event to the last form I create. This seems to work well, though.

```
createContent: function(oController) {
    var that = this;

    this.addEventDelegate({
        onBeforeShow: function(oEvent) {
            // load data
        }
    });

    this.oVBox = new sap.m.VBox("vbox");

    this.oVBox.setModel(this.oModel);

    this.bFirst = true;

    this.oVBox.bindAggregation("items", {
        path: "/",
        factory: function(siD, oContext) {
            // create form and set binding context
            // ugly hack:
            if (that.bFirst === true) {
                that.bFirst = false;
                oForm.onAfterRendering = function() {
                    that._onAfterFormRendering();
                }
            }
            return oForm;
        }
    });

    // default is read only
    this.oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        content: [ this.oVBox ]
    });

    return this.oPage;
},

_onAfterFormRendering: function() {
    this.oPage.setBusy(false);
    // handle printing
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code of what you've tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try jquery Page onAfterShow

```
onInit : function() {
    this.getView().addEventDelegate({
             onAfterShow : jQuery.proxy(function(evt) {
                   this.onAfterShow(evt);
              }, this)
         });
},


onAfterShow : function(evt) {

//Try reading the data from the forms here

    }
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.Else, please post more code to understand the issue better.

Comment: Well, the issue is that the form needs time after the page is shown and while the rendering is processed. During that time you can see the different forms grow...